# How to make all widgets appear to be of same size in GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using GridView to show a different students on screen. I am using my custom made cards to show a student. Now, if the name of a student is very large, it is taking more space and rest of the cards are remaining of same size.

At first, when the name was too large, I was getting an error for less space. Then to fix that, I changed aspect ratio. But now, my screen seems too ditorted. Can you please help me out on how to fix this?

Here are the code snippets -

First, my card -

```
class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback function;
  final BoxDecoration? bor;
  final String? board;
  final String? standard;

  const CardItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.title,
    required this.function,
    this.bor,
    this.board,
    this.standard
  })
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: function,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            color: cardColor,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(getProportionateScreenHeight(22)),
              decoration: bor,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50.0,
                    child: imageUrl,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(11),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    title,
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyText2!
                        .apply(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 7.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          board??"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: brandPurple,
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          standard??"",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: brandPurple,
                            fontSize: 13,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How I used them in GridView -

```
                            child: GridView.count(
                              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                              crossAxisSpacing:
                                  getProportionateScreenWidth(25.0),
                              mainAxisSpacing:
                                  getProportionateScreenHeight(0.0),
                              childAspectRatio: 2 / 3,
                              shrinkWrap: false,
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              children: [
                                for (int i = 0; i < dataList.length; i++)
                                  CardItem(
                                    imageUrl: dataList[i].avtar == null
                                        ? Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/profile_pic.png')
                                        : CachedNetworkImage(
                                            imageUrl: dataList[i].avtar!,
                                            imageBuilder:
                                                (context, imageProvider) =>
                                                    Container(
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                                image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: imageProvider,
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            placeholder: (context, url) =>
                                                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            errorWidget:
                                                (context, url, error) =>
                                                    Icon(Icons.error),
                                            // httpHeaders: {
                                            //   "Authorization":
                                            //       'JWT ' + token,
                                            // },
                                          ),
                                    title: dataList[i].name!,
                                    board: getBoard(
                                        dataList[i].student_current_board),
                                    standard: getGrade(
                                        dataList[i].student_current_board,
                                        dataList[i].grade),
                                    function: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        selected_id = dataList[i].id!;
                                        print(dataList[i].name);
                                        Provider.of<APIData>(context,
                                                listen: false)
                                            .initializeCurrentStudent(
                                                dataList[i]);
                                      });
                                    },
                                    bor: selected_id == dataList[i].id!
                                        ? border_light()
                                        : BoxDecoration(),
                                  ),
                                Add(
                                  imageUrl:
                                      'assets/images/add_profile_icon.svg',
                                  title: 'Add Profile',
                                  function: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => AddProf()),
                                    ).then((value) => refresh());
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
```

Here is the UI that I am getting -

[image]

Comment: One workaround (barely a solution) would be to cut off a name if it's too long, using the `overflow` property of the `Text` Widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/overflow.html

Comment: @fravolt Nah bro, I need to display the full name.

Comment: As an aside, it's difficult to get it running. Is it possible for you to make a more minimal example? Maybe include a screenshot too showcasing the issue

Comment: If you need to display full name and you want to have same size, you need to know the longest name and size all Cards accordingly, and this can be problematic (think of different screen sizes, adaptive font size controlled by user etc.).

Comment: So either you set a fix size and use some overflow handling as suggested by @fravolt, or you have to accept that Card sizes will be different. [This package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) for example can make nice grid view from variable size items.

Comment: Like @fravolt said you can use `overflow` and you can also add `maxLines`.

Comment: You can use [auto_size_text](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package to make the text of full name fit in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
childAspectRatio: 0.75,
```

It will fix the height / width for **all** items.

Check the below code for example

```
class ItemCardGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItemCardGridView(
  {Key? key,
  required this.crossAxisCount,
  required this.padding,
  required this.items})
  // we plan to use this with 1 or 2 columns only
  : assert(crossAxisCount == 1 || crossAxisCount == 2),
    super(key: key);
  final int crossAxisCount;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  // list representing the data for all items
  final List<ItemCardData> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
    padding: padding,
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
      mainAxisSpacing: 40,
      crossAxisSpacing: 24,
      // width / height: fixed for *all* items
      childAspectRatio: 0.75,
    ),
    // return a custom ItemCard
    itemBuilder: (context, i) => ItemCard(data: items[i]),
    itemCount: items.length,
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following package for equal and beautiful gridviews.
Here's the link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view
In this package you can use Masonry Gridview which will surely help you!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33554138)